# Cant run my python project with kivy on raspberry [CRITICAL] [Window] Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3, kivymd, adafruit

am working on a python project for school, creating a graphical interface using kivy for naomi games, and integrat it with raspberry pi 3 and adafruit piTFT 3.5 screen.

the project works perfectly on my pc, but on raspberry this is my logs :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/kivydimmboot $ python3.9 main.py -d                                                                   [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-03-08_8.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.0 (default, Mar  8 2023, 00:35:33)
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/local/bin/python3.9"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.resourcefind> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <x11> (import error)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm' from 'kivy.lib.vidcore_lite' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite/__init__.py)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1109, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: b''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 165, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1071, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 306, in create_window
    self.system_size = _size = self._win.setup_window(
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 114, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 76, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1109, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

[DEBUG  ] [Text        ] Provider <pango> ignored by config
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2022-10-13 (installed at "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

i already added those lines to my main.py, but nothing works

```
# Setup touchscreen
 os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']= 'fbcon'
 os.environ['SDL_FBDEV']= '/dev/fb1'
 os.environ['SDL_MOUSEDRV'] = 'TSLIB'
 os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDEV"] = '/dev/input/touchscreen'


# for raspberry
 os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'egl_rpi'  # https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html
 os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
```